# ISMP silent mode installation on Linux

Tags: installshield

I'm trying to install some software packaged using ISMP (InstallShield Multi Platform). I'm trying to do a silent mode install something like ./setup.bin -silent which does the installation completely. But, I want to have an option to install specific features using some properties file or something similar in silent mode. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.